Sufficient condition for matrix factorization as an undirected graph random walk matrix
Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ row-stochastic matrix.
Is there a sufficient condition for $A$ to be factorized as $D^{-1} W$, where $W$ is a symmetric adjacency matrix for a weighted graph and $D=W\mathbf{1}$ is the diagonal matrix of row sums?
Clearly, the symmetry of $W$ would imply that if $A$ can be factorized this way, then $A$ must be structurally symmetric, that is, $A_{ij} > 0 \Leftrightarrow A_{ji} > 0$. However, I can't tell if this structural symmetry of $A$ is also sufficient for this factorization.
